# Mock modular forms and (indefinite) quadratic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, quadratic-forms

Define the function
$$f(q,z,y) = \sum_{n \ge 0,m,l} c(n,m,l) q^n z^m y^l$$
 where $c(n,m,l)$ is defined by
$$ c(n,m,l) = 
\begin{cases}
(-1)^{s+l} & \text{if } 4n - m^2 + l^2 = 2s(s+1)\\
0 & \text{otherwise}  
\end{cases}
$$
for some integer $s$ and $c(n,m,l) = 0$ unless $4n - m^2 -l^2 \ge 0.$
$f(q,z,1)$ is known to be related to a Mock modular form.  I conjecture that
$$f(q,1,-1) = \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n (2n + 1) q^{n(n+1)/2}.$$
Is there an elementary proof of the above conjecture?
Is the function $f(q,z,y)$ a known mathematical object, perhaps related to a Siegel modular form?

Update:
$f(q,z,y)$ is a product of Jacobi theta functions and $\mu(q;z,y),$
where $\mu(q;z,y)$ is a Lerch sum studied by Zweger in his thesis.  Zweger's thesis also relates mock modular forms to indefinite quadratic forms of signature $(1,n),$ so perhaps it isn't too unsurprising that $f(q,z,y)$ takes a "nice" form.

Comment: Why isn't there any $z$ dependence on the rhs of your equation for $f(q,z,-1)$? Also, can you provide details on the relation between f(q,z,1) and a specific mock modular form?

Comment: @Jeff Harvey - Thanks!  Typo fixed and (some) details added.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but one place that Appell-Lerch sums show up is in the Polar part of meromorphic Jacobi forms.
The recent paper arXiv:1208.4074 by Dabholkar, Murthy and Zagier has a detailed treatment of the relation between meromorphic Jacobi forms and mock modular forms along with many examples. 